# Fantasy manga about a noble main character frowned upon due to a lack of magic skills, and abused by his fiancée

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

From what I can remember, the main character (MC) is some sort of young noble who was frowned upon by people around him, due to how skittish and incompetent he was in magic.

He also had a fiancée that looked down on him and abused him *(IIRC in later chapters, her reasons were to keep him for herself, due to jealousy)*. At one point, the MC either left the household or was kicked out. He was forced to go adventuring on his own. His fiancée soon went out to search for him out of regret.

I think he also met a travelling female mage, who would later meet up with the fiancée and confront her for her abusive treatment of the MC.

Anyone got any idea what this manga was called?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white, and was the travelling mage male or female?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking your time replying. I remember the manga is mostly in black and white, and I believe the mage was a female character.

Comment: Is the fiance also an adventurer or otherwise skilled with a sword? The MC was hated because he was weak, but did it turn out that he was actually extremely strong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Hazure Skill "Gacha" de Tsuihou Sareta Ore wa, Wagamama Osananajimi o Zetsuen Shi Kakusei Suru](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=176177)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Crest was born as the fifth son of a duke. However, as the fifth son, he was in no position to talk. His childhood friend and also his fiancée, Ellis, treated him just like a slave. And on Crest's coming-of-age ceremony, he received a skill called "Gacha." Yet, he wasn't able to learn how to use it and was banished away from his home. Banished into the forest full of monsters, Crest began to understand the power "Gacha." And then, Crest made up his mind. He will definitely survive and get back on his feet.

The protagonist, Crest Bahurst, is the fifth son of a duke, and lives in Resifel, the royal capital of the kingdom of Rakind. Unfortunately, his mother died giving birth to him, and as a result, his father resents him and he's bullied by his four older brothers.

He has a fiancée named Ellis Rifeld, who also bullies him because she's insecure about losing him to other girls, and wants to lower his self-esteem to decrease the prospect of that happening. She's especially jealous of a girl named Minue Mycelian, who's in the department of knighthood along with Crest, in the academy attended by all three, and spends more time with him there, since Ellis is in the department of nobility.

In the first chapter, Crest has recently turned 15 years of age, which means it's his turn to attend an appraisal ceremony where he'll receive a skill of his own as a blessing from God. Crest places his hand on a stone monument which reveals his skill as [Gacha]. Crest's father asks him to demonstrate his skill right then and there, in front of the crowd in attendance. However, while Crest is able to bring up a menu screen, he's the only one who can see it, and he can't activate his skill yet because he doesn't have enough points.

Since he can't get his skill to work then and there, his brothers start heckling him, and his father becomes enraged, feeling ashamed of him, and abruptly declares that he's exiled. Crest is escorted by armed guards to a magic circle, which is to be used to transport him to the Lower World, where monsters dwell. Just before the transport, he persuades one of the guards to give him a sword, promising that he'll use to defeat as many monsters as possible in order to redeem himself.

Shortly after arriving in the lower world, Crest is confronted by a wolf monster and uses the sword to kill it. In doing so, he discovers that killing monsters earns him the points he needs to activate his [Gacha] skill, through which he can buy all manner of other skills, provided he has enough points. He soon gets busy earning more points and upgrading his skill set.

Back at Resifel, Ellis and Minue learn that they've both been summoned by the king. Not only them, but their families as well, plus Crest's family, since the three families are headed by the three Great Dukes of the kingdom. It transpires that the king has received a letter from the Pope, who's foreseen that a large number of monsters will attack the kingdom in the near future.

The letter specifies three skills which are required to combat this threat. The first is Ellis' skill, [Blessing of the Saint]. The second is Minue's skill, [Strike of the Hero]. And the third is Crest's skill, [Gacha]. This is when the king learns, much to his dismay, of Crest's banishment by his own father.

It's determined that Minue should be sent to the Lower World to bring Crest home, but Ellis objects, stating that as Crest's fiancée, she should be the one to go. Minue raises her own objection to this, telling the king that Crest confided in her about the bullying he received from Ellis, asserting that he might run away or even kill himself if he sees her again.

The king gets fed up of listening to the two girls taking shots at one another, and declares that he doesn't care who goes; he just wants Crest brought back immediately. And so the girls grudgingly agree that they'll both go, which is about all they can agree on.

The manga is still ongoing, and they haven't caught up to Crest yet in any of the chapters currently translated into English.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes this was the one! I really appreciate the help, as this was just stuck at the back of my mind for a while and I kept hitting dead ends when I was searching for it. Thank you!